# Unique index ignored when updating with Mongoose + Mockgoose in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using Mongoose ODM to manage database connections to MongoDB in a NodeJS application, and intercepting the connection using Mockgoose in Mocha tests. I've ran into an issue where my unique indexes are being ignored when performing an update to a document. I'm simply wrapping Mongoose with another package called Mongoose-bird, which just enables the use of promises.

One schema in particular is as follows:

```
// Gallery.js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose-bird')(require("mongoose"));
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);

var GallerySchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    type: String,
    title: String,
    slug: String,
    _albums: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Albums'
    }]
});

GallerySchema.index({ slug: 1 }, { unique: true });
GallerySchema.plugin(deepPopulate, {});
mongoose.model('Galleries', GallerySchema);
```

When calling `Gallery.update(conditions, data, opts)` from my controller in a test, purposely setting the `slug` to be a duplicate of another, it updates the document and then I end up with two documents with the same `slug` path.

FYI, I've found a way around this by using the `save()` function instead, which seems to obey the unique index without any questions.

However, as I'd prefer to use `update()` over `save()` (i.e. to update documents partially as opposed to the whole document each time), I'm interested to know if anyone else has had this same issue and how you have overcome it?

The application follows a standard MVC pattern based on MEAN.js so there's a bit more to it than just one model, though if I've left out anything which may be useful, please let me know.

**Update**
After looking into the source code of the Mockgoose NPM module, I can confirm the validation against the schema is never performed when running update(). There is an issue logged here: http://www.github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose/issues/58

Comment: Can you update your question with the shell output from `db.galleries.getIndexes()`?

Comment: When I'm back on my workstation, I will update it. However, I am using Mockgoose which intercepts the Mongoose connection, so it doesn't communicate with the actual database, but just an in-memory one it creates.

Comment: Ok, never mind then; I didn't catch that it was a Mockgoose problem.

Comment: All good! I was concerned it may have been an issue with the database itself, but updating via the Mongo CLI does throw a constraint error. I'm sure the database is working correctly, I think it may be a Mockgoose bug, but I'm yet to determine if it is or if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are using `mockgoose.reset` in a test hook (e.g. `afterEach`). It drops the database and the indexes aren't created again during the execution.

The solution is removing models separately.

Comment: Please, when you downvote write a comment with a reason so I can improve the answer.

Comment: Hi, this was the correct solution for me too! Thanks @DiegoHaz. Using Jest and Mongoose (not with Mockgoose) - just using local Mongo instance (via Docker) for e2e tests, the Unique Index was getting ignored, but only in tests. The code itself was working fine. The cleanup I was doing in `beforeEach` was deleting all the Collections, which was what another test needed, but it also wiped the Unique Indexes. Solution was to create a new test file which does not use the offending cleanup code.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to [Diego's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5513909/diego-haz) post. Calling `mockgoose.helper.reset()` in a test hook to probably clear the collections in the temporary store also removes the indexes.
You should reset the indexes after calling reset using the snippet below.

```
await mockgoose.helper.reset()
const db = mongoose.connection
db.modelNames().map(async (model) => {
  await db.models[model].createIndexes()
})
```

This fixed the problem for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped me buddy, thanks a million! I just wish I'd found your post about 3 hours before I did!

Answer (score 0):

From the mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

> When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls
>   ensureIndex for each defined index in your schema. Mongoose will call
>   ensureIndex for each index sequentially, and emit an 'index' event on
>   the model when all the ensureIndex calls succeeded or when there was
>   an error.
>
> While nice for development, it is recommended this behavior
>   be disabled in production since index creation can cause a significant
>   performance impact. Disable the behavior by setting the autoIndex
>   option of your schema to false, or globally on the connection by
>   setting the option config.autoIndex to false.

Since, mongoose sets the index on start, you got to debug the specific error, why mongoDb is not allowing to index, using the following code

```
//keeping autoIndex to true to ensure mongoose creates indexes on app start
GallerySchema.set('autoIndex', true);
//enable index debugging
GallerySchema.set('emitIndexErrors', false);
GallerySchema.on('error', function(error) {
  // gets an error whenever index build fails
});
GallerySchema.index({ slug: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Also, make sure `autoIndex` is not set to false as mentioned in the mongoose doc, or better set it true explicitly as done above.

Additonally,

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

The debug logging will show you the `ensureIndex` call it's making for you to create the index.

Comment: I will try this out when I'm back on my workstation, however I believe Mongoose and MongoDB are working OK - when I try to update in Mongo CLI directly, it throws a constraint error. It's just when testing using Mockgoose where it's ignored. I'll give it a shot and let you know how I go.

Comment: the solution I am saying will inform you about the constraint error in Mongoose. You got to fix the constraint error as per MongoDB's requirement

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not getting any additional output from the above, which I have a feeling Mongoose is doing what it should, but Mockgoose is not behaving correctly.

Comment: you mean mongoose is not reporting the indexing error? do you see in console ensureIndex being called?

Comment: No errors are being reported when running my test, the duplicate key is simply allowed. I came across this issue which seems to be the same issue, but it looks like the topic died off: https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose/issues/58