# Mongoose indexes don't get created half the time on Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

Whenever I run my Mocha test, it alternates between creating the index and not creating it. I thought it somehow wasn't creating the index because the tests might have run before it finished, but since it alternates in a pattern like that, I don't think that's the case. I also thought it might have something to do with me dropping the database at the start of every test, but that shouldn't somehow effect only every other test.

The index in question:

```
submissionSchema.index({ studentID: 1, assignmentID: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

The code to to drop the database:

```
before(function(done){
    mongoose.createConnection(require(__dirname + '/../app/config').mongoURL, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: mongoose creates indexes using various `.ensureIndex()` ( yes that is still the call ) methods for defined indexes "on database connection". You are explicitly calling `.dropDatabase()` from the underlying driver method "after" connection. In short, what else would you expect when you blow away the database? If you expect "indexes" to remain in place, then rather call `.remove()` on the collection/model(s) in question. This will not "drop" either index or collection ( or indeed database ) but merely invalidate content until new data is inserted.

Comment: Why does it work every other time? If removes the indexes after they're created, shouldn't the indexes never appear?

Comment: They likely do not. Can you show a reproducible case where you are calling `.dropDatabase()` and there are still indexes available afterwards? At any rate, I'm sure it's "pot luck" and especially if index creation is being asked to run in "background" mode. If you want a solid behaviour then you are best off scripting the index creation stage yourself. The "default behavior" of mongoose index creation is really considered a "development convienience", and also recommends turning this option off in production environments.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the problem by just calling ensureIndexes on each model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blake Sevens was right. To fix this, I just rebuilt the indexes after I dropped the database.

```
before(function(done){
    mongoose.createConnection(require(__dirname + '/../app/config').mongoURL, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err){
            if (err) throw err;

            var rebuildIndexes = []

            var models = Object.keys(mongoose.connections[0].base.modelSchemas);

            models.forEach(function(model){
                rebuildIndexes.push(function(cb){
                    mongoose.model(model, mongoose.connections[0].base.modelSchemas[model]).ensureIndexes(function(err){
                        return cb(err);
                    })
                });
            });

            async.parallel(rebuildIndexes, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Dumped database and restored indexes');
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: User dondrzzy has a much shorter alternative here. I don't think it rebuilds the indexes in parallel like this one but that doesn't seem to take very long anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594499/unique-index-ignored-when-updating-with-mongoose-mockgoose-in-nodejs
TL;DR
db.modelNames().map(async (model) => {
  await db.models[model].createIndexes()
})